# Binding C-[ in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to bind "C-[" like so:

```
(define-key py-mode-map "\C-["  'py-shift-region-left)
```

The problem is, Emacs sees "C-[" as ESC. Am I missing something?

Comment: The function `describe-key` confirms this: `(describe-key [?\C-\[])`. I've been searching around, looking for an answer, and so far can't find an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Well, as it happens, "\C-[" and ESC are the same character. They are also being reported as the same by `xkbwatch`, which leads me to believe that `X` is reporting those keypresses to applications in the same way, so there's nothing to be done on the Emacs side of things. As for somehow making "\C-[" not act like ESC at a lower level, unfortunately I've no idea, I always considered it a pinky-saving feature.

Comment: Note that I see the same *effect* using GNU Emacs on Windows, not involving X in any way. Remapping at the X level may offer a way around this problem, but it seems that Emacs has some assumptions built in that must be overcome as well.

Comment: And the same effect on Linux console, too.